# How should I manage data classes of various subtypes?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, data-class, freezed

This is my problem, imagine you need to show a table of clients, there you only need to show about 4 fields of the data class Client:

- Name
- Last Name
- Birthday
- Id

But when I go to the details of a client I need to see a the fields above and some others, like:

- Name
- Last Name
- Birthday
- Id
- Place of birth
- Languages they speak
- Etc.

What I've been doing its creating a data classes for each one, but I feel like there's got to be a better way to do this, I'm looking into GraphQL to be able to use a single endpoint and not need to create an API for each data class that's different for a couple of fields.
I'm also looking into unions with the package Freezed, but I'm not really sure if that's the purpose of unions so I would like to know if someone could help me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply create separate models like "Client" and "ClientDetails"?

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but just thought that maybe there was a better way to do it